Hamburger icon programmatically?
In my simple app I would like to add a hamburger icon to one of my views.
In order to minimize my effort (i.e. spare me the definition of XML files, inclusion of .PNG files, and what not) I would like to do this programmatically, i.e. just write something like:
        ImageView icon = new ImageView(getContext());
        icon.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.???);
        ...
        toolbar.addView(icon);

What would be a correct replacement for the ??? here? I searched for a while but couldn't locate any useful icon. Is there really no hamburger icon predefined in android.R (or any other system library)?
In case this matters: I am developing for Android v13+

If you have appcompat as a dependency already, you can do this: icon.setImageDrawable(new DrawerArrowDrawable(getContext())). That's the Drawable class used by ActionBarDrawerToggle for its hamburger-arrow icon. It's in hamburger state by default.

That was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot! If you make this into an answer I'll happily accept it as solution. BTW: There is no website that provides an overview (i.e. lists these built-in icons, their names and/or how to access them and how they look like), is there?

@Mike-M I only noticed now that this does not work for me. In my code I attach a ClickListener to that icon but for some reason that doesn't work anymore with the above construct. :-(

That's nothing to do with the Drawable; they don't intercept touch events or anything. https://i.sstatic.net/EvTYj1ZP.gif Indeed, this is basically what ActionBarDrawerToggle itself is doing internally: sets the Drawable on an ImageView, then sets an OnClickListener on it.
